# Code Duplication Error - Two libraries contain the same classes - Gradle , Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

I am working on a project in Android Studio where there are included two versions of the library lib signal, the default version was: 0.1.4. I have added another version that is 2.8.1. The reason why I have added another version of the library is that the default version, which is also the newest version, doesn't include anymore some of the classes that the older version (2.8.1) does.

On my `build.gradle` file, here is the way I have included the 2.8.1 version :

```
dependencies {
    lintChecks project(':lintchecks')

    implementation ('androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0') {
        force = true
    }
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
}
```

The problem is that I am having a code of duplication error because the older version contains some classes which are exactly the same as the newer version.
My question is: How can I include the older version and exclude the classes that already exist in the other version?